# How to fit or format text that is in block in dropdown-menu

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem fitting text into blocks (dropdown menu) in CSS.

The code is in Serbian language, but if needed i can translate it to english.

Ok, so i have "Ponuda usluga", when i mouse over that, i get dropdown menu with "Lov" , "Obuka Pasa", "Ribolov" and "Obezbedjivanje potrebne dokumentacije", but the problem is the last one does not fit and proceedes to go under in next line, like shown on screenshot1 here https://ibb.co/YbTytJw (NOTE: at the screenshot i was hovering over "ribolov", thats why its orange).
I would like it to be like this screnshot2 https://ibb.co/dW65Tyx.

Same problem when i hover over "Lov" (that opens a new dropdown menu with 2 options there) like shown on screenshot3 https://ibb.co/0ZKxVWj (Note: I added >> to point out that there is another dropdown menu, and again, i was hovering over "lov", so thats why its orange). Same as the first problem, i need it to say "lov na sitnu divljac" and underneath "lov na krupnu divljac", instead it says "lov na sitnu", "lov na krupnu" and underneath "divljac". I need it to be like screenshot4 https://ibb.co/8zspMY0.

```
<style>

    *{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }


    html{

        height:100%;

    }


    .wrapper{

        min-height:100%;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
    }

    body{

        height:100%;
        background:#ddd;

    }

    h2{
        padding:50px;
        background-color:#161B21;
        color:#f0f1f5;
        font-family: big john;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:30pt;
        letter-spacing:15px;

    }

    .navigationDesktop{

        background-color:#161B21;

    }

    nav{
        height:40px;
        width:700px;
        display:block;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        text-transform: uppercase;

    }

    nav a{

        display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:monospace;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family:13pt;
        color:white;


    }

    nav a:hover{
        background-color:#F4A950;
        color:#f0f1f5;
    }

    nav ul{

        list-style:none;

    }

    nav ul li{
        float:left;
        width:140px;
        height:40px;
        line-height:40px;
        background-color:#161B21;
        list-style-type: none;

    }

    nav ul ul li{
        position:relative;
        display:none;

    }

    nav ul ul ul{
        display:none;
    }

    nav ul li:hover ul li{
        display:block;
        animation: navmenu 500ms forwards;
    }

    @keyframes navmenu{
        0%{
            opacity:0;
            top:5px;

        }
        100%{
            opacity:1;
            top:0px;

        }
    }

    nav ul ul li:hover ul{
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        width:140px;
        left:140px;
        top:0px;

    }



</style>
```

Here is the pastebin of the HTML https://pastebin.com/MLweR454

And here is the pastebin of the CSS https://pastebin.com/mtszKhNu

Comment: Just for the record, i dont want to sound like that i need help. I do, but all im looking for is "how to style or format text in block that is in dropdown menu". Ill figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you are trying to set each nav link block size by using `line-height:40px`, that creates 40px of space between each line of text. What you want do to is set your nav a to `line-height:1.1;`, no px, and make the size of the link block be based of the amount of text and padding, by adding `padding: 15px 0;`